# Spring Boot - How to execute a method when program loses connection to DB?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, cassandra

Fairly new to spring boot here. I've been working on a microservice that connects to two databases, one Cassandra and one Oracle. They contain the same information, because the Cassandra database is replacing the Oracle database as the primary database for this project, however, we are keeping the oracle database as a fallback for if the Cassandra database goes down.

I'm unsure how to tell my application to "do something" when I encounter a loss of connection. My console outputs the following when it loses connection to Cassandra-

```
2019-09-06 14:23:15.127 ERROR 2836 --- [-reconnection-0] c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection        : [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 1000 milliseconds
2019-09-06 14:23:15.147 ERROR 2836 --- [-reconnection-0] c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection        : [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 1000 milliseconds
2019-09-06 14:23:16.134 ERROR 2836 --- [-reconnection-0] c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection        : [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 2000 milliseconds
2019-09-06 14:23:16.149 ERROR 2836 --- [-reconnection-0] c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection        : [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 2000 milliseconds
2019-09-06 14:23:23.137 ERROR 2836 --- [-reconnection-1] c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection        : [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 4000 milliseconds
```

And it keeps going like that, doubling timeout, until it can reconnect.

Is it possible to fire a method when this happens? If I could just change a variable's value in my controller when the connection is lost, everything would work fine, but I can't seem to find any information on the topic. Is there a different way to handle this I'm not even thinking about, like maybe a bool that changes based on the connection? Sorry if that sounds misguided, I'm just really grasping at straws here.

Additionally, is it possible to fire an event when the connection is reestablished?

Thanks for your help. I really appreciate any advice.

As a PS- I'm not sure how helpful this code will be, but I feel like I should at least give some context to my situation.

Here's my cassandra config

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cassandra")
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
public class CassandraConfiguration {

    private String clusterName;
    private String hostNames;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String keyspace;
    private boolean sslEnabled;
    private int port;
    private int fetchSize;
    private String localDC;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public Session cassandraSession() {
        String[] hostname = hostNames.split(",");
        Cluster cluster = null;

        LoadBalancingPolicy loadBalancingPolicy = new TokenAwarePolicy(
                DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder()
                        .withLocalDc(localDC)
                        .build()
        );

        PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
        poolingOptions
                .setConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL,  4, 10)
                .setConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2, 4)
                .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 32768)
                .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2000);

        if (isSslEnabled()) {

            cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(hostname)
                    .withClusterName(clusterName)
                    .withCredentials(username, password)
                    .withPort(port)
                    .withoutJMXReporting()
                    .withSSL()
                    .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM))
                    .withLoadBalancingPolicy(loadBalancingPolicy)
                    .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
                    .build();

        } else {
            cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(hostname)
                    .withClusterName(clusterName)
                    .withCredentials(username, password)
                    .withPort(port)
                    .withoutJMXReporting()
                    .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM))
                    .withLoadBalancingPolicy(loadBalancingPolicy)
                    .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
                    .build();
        }

        cluster.getConfiguration().getCodecRegistry()
                .register(LocalDateCodec.instance)
                .register(InstantCodec.instance);
        Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);

        return session;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingManager mappingManager() {
        return new MappingManager(cassandraSession());
    }

}
```

Here's my jdbc config for oracle

```
@ConfigurationProperties("jdbc")
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "jdbc.accessService", havingValue = "enabled")
public class JDBCConfig {
    @Autowired
    SshTunnel sshTunnel;

    private String driver;
    private String url;
    private String user;
    private String password;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Connection jdbcConnection() {
        Connection jdbcConnection = null;

        try {
            jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection (url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connection Established");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jdbcConnection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to recognize lost connections ?

Comment: @Marged So I can route input from my controller to the other database(oracle) in the event that a connection is lost. I think that always attempting to query the cassandra database and error catching, then querying the oracle database would add a lot of latency. I'd like to just have it query the Oracle database directly after I know the connection is lost.

Comment: I think the concept you're looking for is a _circuit breaker_; the standard default these days is resilience4j.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks so much! That's exactly what I needed. I just did some reading about it, and think it'll cover all my needs. I am willing to accept that as an answer if you'd like to submit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need a *circuit breaker*, which is a software component that watches for failures of some wrapped service, tries to detect when it's available again, and can redirect to some other implementation or let exceptions escape in a failure condition.

The current apparent default (and my recommendation) is [resilience4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker).